# Java FX stage show function not working on mac

Tags: java, macos, javafx

I hope somebody will be able to help me with this : I'm on macOS and even though I put stage.show() at the end of my start method, when I run my program a strange "java" folder appears at the bottom but I can't open it nor close it

```
public class Main extends Application {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    
    Group root = new Group();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    
    
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

}

Is there a way to fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating your own stage you should use the primaryStage provide to you. Why don't you just start with a working template from one of the many sources? And what is your stage going to show anyway? It contains just a scene with an empty group.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I'm trying to follow a tutorial because I've never worked with JavaFX. Here's the link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9XJicRt_FaI&ab_channel=BroCode as you can see, at 27:14 (for instance), a blank window appears. But it doesn't in my case. Even after I tried to put text in it. Also, I tried at first to use the primaryStage provided but it didn't work, that's why I tried to create my own stage.

Answer (score 0):

After 5 hours of googling I found it. You need to go to Run->Run configurations->Argument and to uncheck "Use the -XstartOnFirstThread argument when launching with SWT"

Comment: This probably happened only because you added the SWT module which you should not use anyway. You could have saved yourself 5 hours by just starting with the official documentation https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/ instead of an arbitrary video from the WWW.